# How to fix AJAX HTTP request which was terminated abnormally?

Tags: 7, ajax

I keep getting this AJAX error message every time when I add taxonomy terms or open view pages with AJAX, to name a few.

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: error
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 4
```

Any suggestions to how I can resolve the problem? I'm using the dev desktop.

Comment: Do you frequently update your modules? Its a relative common problem, which will get fixed soon, if its a popular module you are using. However, you should probably try to locate the problem a bit further!

Comment: For Drupal 7 you may try to apply the following core patch: [D7-fix_autocomplete_terminated_error-1232416-179-do-not-test.patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416#comment-8748879).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue sounds like yours: [Drupal alerts "An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally" during normal site operation, confusing site visitors/editors](http://drupal.org/node/1232416)

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7 you may try to apply the following core patch: [D7-fix_autocomplete_terminated_error-1232416-179-do-not-test.patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416#comment-8748879) which goes like:

```
--- a/misc/ajax.js
+++ b/misc/ajax.js
@@ -448,7 +448,10 @@ Drupal.ajax.prototype.getEffect = function (response) {
  * Handler for the form redirection error.
  */
 Drupal.ajax.prototype.error = function (response, uri) {
-  alert(Drupal.ajaxError(response, uri));
+  // Fix for autocomplete terminated error.
+  if (response.status != 0) {
+    alert(Drupal.ajaxError(response, uri));
+  }
   // Remove the progress element.
   if (this.progress.element) {
     $(this.progress.element).remove();
diff --git a/misc/autocomplete.js b/misc/autocomplete.js
index 8f7ac60..980c1ca 100644
--- a/misc/autocomplete.js
+++ b/misc/autocomplete.js
@@ -306,7 +306,10 @@ Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search = function (searchString) {
         }
       },
       error: function (xmlhttp) {
-        alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
+        // Fix for autocomplete terminated error.
+        if (xmlhttp.status != 0) {
+          alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
+        }
       }
     });
   }, this.delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been seeing this lately. Mine popped up immediately and did not have the turning indicator at all.

I have come to a post at [Required autocomplete reference field gives "ReadyState: 0" ajax error](https://www.drupal.org/node/1864828) #5 @jenlampton gave ma a Clue as to my problem. Although I did use http and not https, I used a link without the www as referenced in my settings.php configuration.

Adding www in my browser made the error disappear.

In conclusion, check your settings.php configuration where 
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com"
if you have https use https, if you have www.example.com do not go to example.com.